# Is it possible to observe a quantum probability distribution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, measurement-problem

Is it possible to observe the probability distribution of a quantum particle in real time? So not to observe A state, which would collapse the wavefunction, but observe the whole wave and its probability distribution? If so, is it possible to manipulate the probabilty distribution in some way without collapsing the wavefunction?